# Force push a floated <div> below another floated <div>

Tags: html, css

Visit for my sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKBfE

here is the css code as well:

```
.bubble
{
text-align:left;
color:white;
float:left;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
background: #95a5a6;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
margin-bottom:2%;
margin-top:2%;
margin-right:300px;
}
```

Theres alot of useless code in there but please reference just the divs with

```
class="bubble" | class="bubble2"
```

As you can see this is a chat box with custom chat bubbles, my "bubble" class is the host and the "bubble2" class is the client.

When "bubble" types in multiple messages they are not stacked rather they are displayed inline and only sometimes stack.

How can i make sure that the each bubble pushes the other one down and floats left for the host and floats right for the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding

```
clear:both;
```

As the first line for both .bubble and .bubble2 fixes it for me? 
Is this what u want?

```
.bubble2
{
  clear: both;
}

.bubble
{
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This does work for me as well, can you elaborate and explain why this is actually a solution? Thanks so much.

Comment: Well, Clear:both; ends the floating of elements.. When you do a float:left, every element after that will also float. If we provide clear:both; on every element, it will stop the floating and then evaluate the rest of the CSS